# dataview webpart expanding the first 3 group headers while keeping the rest collapsed

Tags: javascript, sorting, stylesheet, grouping, dataview

I have a dataview webpart where items are sorted based on the startdate and grouped by the StartDate. So there will be items for Different Start dates, grouped under the Dates. In sharepoint designer, we can either expand all the group headers or have them collapsed by default on pageload. Is it possible to get a mix of the two. Like have first three expanded and the rest collapsed. Where would I make change to get this functionality?

```
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.groupheader0">
   <xsl:param name="fieldtitle" />
   <xsl:param name="fieldname" />
   <xsl:param name="fieldvalue" />
   <xsl:param name="fieldtype" />
   <xsl:param name="nodeset" />
   <xsl:param name="groupid" />
   <xsl:param name="displaystyle" />
   <xsl:param name="imagesrc" />
   <xsl:param name="alttext" />
   <xsl:param name="altname" />
   <xsl:param name="hidedetail" />
   <xsl:param name="showheader" />
   <xsl:param name="showheadercolumn" />
   <xsl:if test="$showheader" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
    <tr id="group{$groupid}" style="display:{$displaystyle}">
     <td class="ms-gb" colspan="99">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$groupid='0' or $groupid='9'">
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$groupid='1'">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$groupid='2'">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$groupid='3'">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$groupid='4'">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$groupid='5'">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$groupid='6'">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:if test="not($hidedetail)" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
       <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript:ExpGroupBy(this);return false;">
        <img src="{$imagesrc}" border="0" alt="{$alttext}" name="{$altname}" /></a>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
      <b>
       <xsl:value-of select="$fieldtitle" />
      </b>
      <xsl:if test="$fieldtitle">: </xsl:if>
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$fieldtype='url'">
        <a href="{$fieldvalue}">
         <xsl:value-of select="$fieldvalue" />
        </a>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$fieldtype='user'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$fieldvalue" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$fieldvalue" />
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a couple of javascript functions to the page:

```
function ExpandXGroups(num_groups_to_expand)
{
 for (i=1; i<=num_groups_to_expand; i++)
 {
  ExpCollGroup('1-' + i + '_','img_1-' + i + '_');
 }
}

function Begin()
{
 ExpandXGroups(3)
}
```

and call the function when the page has finished loading:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Begin");
```